# subscribe service method not covering in unit test case jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine

I m trying to write test case for subscribe method.
[code to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGOkd.png)

When I test with

```
ng test --code-coverage true
```

Test case is passing, but in code coverage report subscribe method is not covered

```
npm run sonar-scanner
```

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, instead copy paste it here

Answer (score 0):

Create a mock service and inject it as providers in `component.spec.ts`:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
export class MockService{

  validate(){
    return of()
  }

  queryUser(){
    return of({username: 'myUser'})
  }

}
```

and then inject as

```
providers : [
  {provide: YourActualService , useClass: MockService}
]
```

and then test it as :

```
it('should initilize user name',()=> {
    component.token = "123";
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.uname).toBe('myUser')
})
```

The `useClass` would replace your `service` of component with our `MockService` in which we are returning an observable using `of()`